# Android phone camera sets "dav" comment in metadata

Tags: linux, exif

Nearly every picture taken by my Android phone has a comment added "dav" in the metadata. I'd like to understand why and if possible stop the comments from being added. <s>They appear to be in EXIF and some other metadata field.</s>

Images taken with fast shutter [hold down shutter release to take a series of images, used for action shots] have the letters "bst" added instead of "dav".

The phone is a Huawei Honor5C (NEM-L51) running Android 6 and EMUI 4.1. I download the photos using Digikam on Kubuntu to my desktop. <s>Even when I strip the "dav" comments from the EXIF comment field, when I upload to Facebook the "dav" comment is read and appears attached to the images; the actual text is in the `XMP:Caption`, `EXIF:Image Description`, and `IPTC:Comment` metadata fields.</s>

It's <s>strange,</s> unwanted, and annoying.

Update: On further investigation, opening in `gwenview` and looking at metadata, the strings "dav" and "bst" arrive with images via `EXIF:Image Description` and digikam had been set to harmonise that with other metadata sections. So it's less mysterious, just one EXIF field is being written.

Comment: Could you update with the more details you mentioned? You said you see it on facebook - but where and how? Any screenshots and more details would be great

Comment: Added note that it's in all of XMP, EXIF and IPTC data.

Comment: It looks like you've answered part of your own question. Is there anything left that you want to ask about?

Comment: I know that the Exif:Image Description is set to "dav" but not why, nor how to stop it - the why and how are the critical parts of the question. Any thoughts?